# Sequelize: insert in bulk

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Node.js, MySQL and Sequelize. I'd like to insert some 10k rows into a table at once. The table has custom `primaryKey` field, that is being set manually. The data are downloaded from web and are overlapping.

I'd like to have a version of `bulkCreate` that wouldn't fail if any of the rows in data have unique keys that are already present in the table. Such kind of things is done in MySQL via `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` construct.

How do I do it in Sequelize?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Pass in an options object to bulkCreate with ignoreDuplicates set to true

```
bulkCreate([...], { ignoreDuplicates: true })
```

Comment: This is mysql only unfortunately, does not work on postgres

Comment: bulkCreate always insert a single record i am not getting solution . and on second insertion attempt it gives error of unique

Comment: Soo.. im using `v5` and i just spent an hour or so debugging why my bulkCreate was not working.  The data you pass into bulkCreate needs to be an array of plain js objects.. not an array of sequelize models.  I had a server response.. i was make modifications and using bulkCreate to perform a bulkUpdate.... you need to run `row.get({plain:true})` on your data to bring it back down to plain js objects.

Answer (score 9):

Yuri's answer will ignore duplicates... there is an option for `updateOnDuplicate`:

> Fields to update if row key already exists (on duplicate key update)? (only supported by mysql & mariadb). By default, all fields are updated.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance

Answer (score 2):

`ProductAttribute.bulkCreate(arrayToUpsert, {updateOnDuplicate: ['id', 'attributeValue'] })`
- this will update each attributeValue with ids indicated in arrayToUpsert

Answer (score 1):

**Below is the correct syntax for bulk update, Tested on "sequelize": "6.0.0"**

```
model.bulkCreate(dataToUpdate, { updateOnDuplicate: ["user_id", "token", "created_at"] })
```

**It will update all the columns specfied in updateOnDuplicate by first column values which are in dataToUpdate**