# how to reduce the number of hits to database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have written a code where every field of the db should be checked if its changed it should be updated. In the code I have written the  number of times that we hit db will be more as there are a lot of components to check with.how to write this efficiently

```
if (compList[i].pname != compFound.name || 
  compList[i].pdesc != compFound.description || 
  compList[i].rurl != compFound.url || 
  compList[i].sourceName !== compFound.component_src_system
) {
  compDao.updateComponentDetails(compList[i], comp.cxid).then(function(component) {
      resolve(component)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      logger.error("Error:", err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: What flavor of DB are you using....optimization differs greatly with DBMS used

Comment: Mysql @Gurbakhshish Singh

Comment: Are you using any ORM or running bare bones off of Driver

Comment: Sequelize @Gurbakhshish Singh

Comment: 1. You can created a function on DB side to give you HASH of fields that you are observing for change. this way you can identify which record needs updating by just comparing the Hashes. 2. when you have a list of objs that needs updating you can do this in 1 trip to DB by using Sequelize bulk update, [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258694/sequelize-update-in-bulk)